# Alternative to JQ for Iterating through JSON Array in Shell

Tags: shell, unix, aws-cli

I have a object

```
items=$(aws dynamodb scan --attributes-to-get Zipcode Id --table-name Test --query "Items[*]" --output json | jq --compact-output '.[]')
for itemValue in $items; do
    aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name Test --key $itemValue
done
```

It deletes all the item sequentially one after the another.
Can someone please suggest how can I achieve the same without using jq. Since it is not allowed on ec2 being a third party command ?
Can it be achieved using any aws-cli commands ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share what items is supposed to be before and after jq?

Comment: The output received from 1st query is in format below:

items = [
{"Zipcode": {"S": "112-12a-skw"},"Id": {"N": "12"}}
{"Zipcode": {"S": "113-12a-skw"},"Id": {"N": "13"}}
....]

Now I want to split every json object and pass it as a parameter to my 
aws delete-item command like below:

aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name 4858_PA.Stg.DynamoRestoreTest_temp1 --key {"Zipcode": {"S": "112-12a-skw"},"Id": {"N": "12"}}
aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name 4858_PA.Stg.DynamoRestoreTest_temp1 --key {"Zipcode": {"S": "113-12a-skw"},"Id": {"N": "13"}}

Comment: [Edit] that one into the question -- though note that generally, we guide people making clarifications that would invalidate existing answers to ask new questions instead.

Answer (score 0):

#### The Original Code Didn't Work In The First Place

```
# THIS IS BROKEN
json_list='["First Item", "Second Item", "Third Item"]'
for itemValue in $(echo "$json_list" | jq --compact-output '.[]'); do
  echo "Got an item: <$itemValue>"
done
```

emits:

```
Got an item: <"First>
Got an item: <Item">
Got an item: <"Second>
Got an item: <Item">
Got an item: <"Third>
Got an item: <Item">
```

Obviously, this is incorrect: It's split on spaces, expanded on globs (a `*` surrounded by whitespace inside a string would be replaced with a list of filenames in the current directory), and has literal quotes where the ones given in JSON were syntactic instead.

---

#### Doing It Right With `jq` Requires A Better Delimiter Selection, And A `while read` Loop

```
# THIS WORKS
json_list='["First Item", "Second Item", "Third Item"]'
while IFS= read -r -d '' itemValue; do
  echo "Got an item: <$itemValue>"
done < <(jq -j '.[] | (., "\u0000")' <<<"$json_list")
```

...emitting as output:

```
Got an item: <First Item>
Got an item: <Second Item>
Got an item: <Third Item>
```

---

#### That Same Answer Can Easily Be Ported To Python

```
json_to_nullsep_py=$(cat <<'EOF'
import json
import sys
for item in json.load(sys.stdin):
    sys.stdout.write(item)
    sys.stdout.write('\x00')
EOF
)

json_to_nullsep() {
  python -c "$json_to_nullsep_py" "$@"
}

while IFS= read -r -d '' itemValue; do
  echo "Got an item: <$itemValue>"
done < <(json_to_nullsep <<<"$json_list")
```

...similarly correctly emits:

```
Got an item: <First Item>
Got an item: <Second Item>
Got an item: <Third Item>
```

Comment: The Original code works fine.

The output received from 1st query is in format below:

items = [
{"Zipcode": {"S": "112-12a-skw"},"Id": {"N": "12"}}
{"Zipcode": {"S": "113-12a-skw"},"Id": {"N": "13"}}
....]

Now I want to split every json object and pass it as a parameter to my 
aws delete-item command like below:

aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name 4858_PA.Stg.DynamoRestoreTest_temp1 --key {"Zipcode": {"S": "112-12a-skw"},"Id": {"N": "12"}}
aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name 4858_PA.Stg.DynamoRestoreTest_temp1 --key {"Zipcode": {"S": "113-12a-skw"},"Id": {"N": "13"}}

Comment: It only "works fine" if your data is uninteresting. The code above demonstrates unambiguously that it's broken with data with spaces, and that's not the only case.